# Key Needs to be Pressed Repeatedly to Start Working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

When I leave my computer alone for around five minutes, to get the "w" key to function I need to spam press it, after which it starts functioning correctly. Holding down the key for ~10 seconds also works. Thoughts?

Comment: Does it only happen with "w"? And does it only happen if your machine was idle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a software issue - you could replicate it with an external keyboard.

It's likely a failure in the wiring or mechanics of the keyboard. Depending on how close the Apple Store is, you might have them check for lint or debris under the key cap.

You could DIY - but the pieces are **very, very** fragile and you might be out some $$ to order a replacement if you break things checking it out.

At the store, they usually have spares on hand and can order the right parts on their dime if they break it during cleaning / servicing.